# Можно ли избавиться от полос работая с радиальным или другим видом градиента?

Tags: css, градиент

Я понимаю причину возникновения данной проблемы, но можно ли каким-то образом обойти этот момент при увеличении прозрачности?

```css
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #333;
}
div {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at 50% 100%, #fff, transparent);
opacity: .1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может как костыль filter: blur() ? Конечно если градиент на бэкграунде и сверху контент то придется поизвращаться с слоями

Answer (score 1):

Можно, если увеличить "промежуток" между двумя цветами. Иными словами, выбрать такие цвета, разница между которыми будет большая.

К тому же, данную проблему разные мониторы видят по разному. На обычных @1 мониторах менее заметно, на ретине больше. На мониторе с плотностью пикселей выше ретины оно вовсе ужасно заметно.

Пример ниже, в разы сглаженнее (даже на retina), так как имеет более широкий диапазон: **#555 -> #111**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side at 50% 100%, #555, #111);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

В текущем контейнере он выглядит хорошо. Но если увеличить контейнер до такого порога, пока количество "промежуточных цветов" закончатся, то градиент снова будет иметь полоски.

**Альтернативное решение**

В вашем случае, если имеется фон и на него нужно наложить прозрачно-белую плешку, то можете воспользоваться **box-shadow**.

Answer (score 1):

Обойти нельзя, это связано с ограничениями цветопередачи, количество градаций серого ограничено цветовым пространством sRGB и их не хватает для каждого пикселя на экране.